# is not under 'rootDir' 'c:/Users/hasit/Desktop/typescript/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files."

Tags: typescript

I am trying to separate the Src folder and public folder separately but when I tried to do it in the tsconnfig .json it comes with this error " 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.". i followed an article on stackflow but still no luck, can anyone please help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5G9HB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the tsconfig file is in the same folder as your project's root directory. From the image, I can see that your project folder is `Desktop/typescript/final`, but your tsconfig file lies in `Desktop/typescript`.

Just move it to your project folder (`final` directory) and it should work.